# When doing FDR correction in graphpad prism after Kruskal-Wallis does the programme automatically perform a Dunn test?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, false-discovery-rate, dunn-test

I used the Benjamini-Hochberg FDR correction in graphad after performing a Kruskal-Wallis test. This gives me a list of individual P-values.

The graphad website says that if you select the FDR option after parametric ANOVA it does a Fischer's LSD method and does FDR on that.

So my question is: If I select the FDR option after Kruskal-Wallis does use some method to like Dunn's to get a list of multiplicity adjusted p-values and correct these?

Answer (score 1):

When controlling for false discovery rate (FDR), it makes little sense to start with p-values that have already been adjusted for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) to control family-wise error rate. In fact, the p-values from the Fisher LSD test performed by GraphPad Prism when FDR is chosen following ANOVA for multiple-comparison correction are [NOT multiplicity-adjusted p-values](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_false_discovery_rate_from_mult.htm); the manual calls this an "unprotected Fisher's LSD test."

The values reported when FDR is used to control for multiple comparisons are generally called "q" values to avoid confusion with the "p" values that represent probabilities of false-positive, Type-I errors. GraphPad Prism seems to follow this practice. So if you are getting a list of things called "p" values it's possible that your request for FDR control has not been respected by the software.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Prism appears to give me both a list of q-values and of p-values (which are different). It was my suspicion that somehow the FDR correction was used to correct the p-values? Based on your answer, you don't think this is the case?

Also, do you happen to know if Fisher's LSD test is also done in Prism after Kruskal-Wallis when you select an FDR method?

Comment: @GerardP I don't have experience with GraphPad Prism and software-specific questions are off-topic here. You would have to check with Prism help about whether there is an FDR correction for reported p-values. For multiple-comparison corrections following Kruskal-Wallis I suspect that the associated non-parametric Mann-Whitney test would be used to get initial uncorrected p-values for pairwise differences, rather than the parametric Fisher's LSD. Again, Prism help from the manufacturer or on help boards would be best to get the answers.